# problem with GaussView 6

Tags: software-installation

Recently I installed Ubuntu 23 and installed all my working applications.
the Gaussian software works perfectly GaussView launches but when I try to open a file with it it crashes.
in version 20 of Ubuntu it works perfectly except in versions 21, 22 or 23 of Ubuntu where I had this problem.
please, is there a way to solve this problem??
THANKS

Comment: Ubuntu's main products are *year.month* in format (eg. 23.04, for 2023-April release, 23.10 for 2023-October release), with the snap only versions using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 22 or the 2022 release) but these only come out on *even* years thus there is no Ubuntu Core 23.  Please clarify your question with valid release details.  Please also clear details of the software; an `apt search` for it provided no results for me, neither did `snap search`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok with ubuntu 20.04 and previous version gaussview works perfectly but with versions 21.04, 22.04, 23.04 and 23.10 I have the problem explained.
the problem: the application launches normally but when I open a file to view it, it crashes with this message: segmentation fault (core dump), the application sometimes freezes without a message.

Comment: @Amd_net please [edit] that information into your question - along with a description of the steps you took to install the application gaussview 6